# What implies the following property of a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to find a condition over a measure $\mu$ over a separable normed vector space $X$ such that for every measurable set $D$,

$\mu(D)>0$  $\implies $  $\exists\delta >0$ such that $\mu(D-x)>0$ for each $x\in X$ such that $\lVert{x}\rVert<\delta$.

Notice that the condition does not hold for an atomic measure. Would it be true if the measure is non-atomic?

Comment: The most common property which would guarantee that is just that the measure is invariant under translation

Comment: Thanks, but is there a weaker condition? If it were a measure absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, would it be true if the measure had full support over an interval, for example?

Comment: @Condor5: I think that for a *finite* measure which is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure, this is always true, without further assumptions. You might even be able to drop the finiteness assumption.